# How do I mock DynamoDB client while isolating other mocked functions/objects?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, aws-sdk

I'm running into an issue mocking an SDK client (DynamoDB) across several tests.

I have created a minimally reproducible example at the following code sandbox: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/compassionate-chandrasekhar-gc8yg5?file=%2Ftest%2Funit%2Flambda-test.test.js%3A1%2C1)

There are two tests attached, and each test essentially calls a Lambda that depends on a set of constants (`TEST_1` and `TEST_2`) and on a DynamoDB client. The difference between the two tests is that the values of the constants mocked are made to be different.

When I run each of these 2 tests solo, they both pass individually. However, when I run the tests sequentially in the same execution (usually test 1 followed by test 2) then the second test fails because of the object equality assertions:

```
Expected: "newtest1"
Received: "test1"

      53 |
      54 |     expect(dynamoDbMock).toHaveReceivedCommand(QueryCommand);
    > 55 |     expect(result.TEST_1).toBe("newtest1");
```

It seems that Jest is **retaining the mocked constant values from test 1 and is not overwriting them in test 2**. This is the main problem that I'm facing.

For reference, I am using AWS SDK v3 and I am using [the mocking library](https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock/) recommended in the AWS blog.

---

At this point, I have tried a few approaches to fix this: essentially, I want both the dependency modules (the constants and the SDK client) to be mocked "from scratch" on each test. What got me the farthest was wrapping each of the test bodies inside `jest.isolateModules()` function blocks.

However, I did not include this in the reproducible example because this actually seems like a more problematic state than before: while the 2 tests seem to "pass", after their execution the console prints strange validation exceptions thrown and when I debug each test, I see they actually fail in the `dynamoDbClient.send()` calls -- I think the DynamoDB client mock is not being used here and it's actually using the real client instance. Somehow, though, Jest still marks the tests as passed. See image below:

[image: Tests pass but exception is thrown at runtime and it looks like the mocked DynamoDB client is not being used.]

What am I doing wrong? I suspect I need a `jest.resetModules()` somewhere but nothing I've tried gets me closer to what I want (i.e. both tests pass without any exceptions thrown at runtime).

Comment: I hope you got some workaround to fix above issue,
Recently I am facing same issue in few services, how did you identify the cause of this ?